# Can I use a copy of a blockchain created on Mac OS X, on an offline Ubuntu (ARMv7) box?

Tags: blockchain, cold-storage, macos, blockchain-import, blockchain-export

I created a wallet on an offline/air-gapped Ubuntu box, but my main computer is a Mac. If I want to sync the offline Ubuntu wallet to check the balance, can I use the blockchain created on my Mac?

If so:

- which folders/files to I copy from my Mac?
- where do I copy/put them in Ubuntu prior to import?
- what are the commands I use once I copy it over to Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to the subject is already here [Is the raw Monero blockchain file different for Linux, Windows, or Mac?](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/2791/is-the-raw-monero-blockchain-file-different-for-linux-windows-or-mac)

There is nothing to import if you just copy the monero data directly.